# Use JDT to extract IcompilationUnits in a standalone Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, compilationunit

I am writting an ordinary Java application and want to extract all ICompilationUnit of an input project (which is not necessary 
developed by Eclipse). As I am not developing an Eclipse plugin, I can't use the below code to extract ICompilationUnit:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IPath path = Path.fromOSString(source.getAbsolutePath());
IFile file = workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(path);
ICompilationUnit compilationUnit = (ICompilationUnit) JavaCore.create(file);
```

Currently, I am using the below code to parse the input Java file. (str contains the source code of input java file)

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS12);
parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

However, the below code return null as it was not created from a Java element.

```
ICompilationUnit icu = (ICompilationUnit)compilationUnit.getJavaElement();
```

Question: Is there any way to extract ICompilationUnits in an ordinary Java Application?

Comment: What do you mean by _"extract ICompilationUnits"_? With a `CompilationUnit` you can do `cu.accept(new ASTVisitor(true) { ... })` to find specific elements.

Comment: I want to use SearchEngine(ICompilationUnit[] workingCopies) and because of that I need to extract ICompilationUnit.

Comment: I see. `getJavaElement` returns `null`, because of `parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());` instead of `parser.setSource(IClassFile)`. I guess it would be easier to use the `ASTVisitor` instead of creating an `IClassFile` and using the `SearchEngine` to find specific elements. What are you searching for?

Comment: I want to find all calls to methods and fields defined in the project. There is an easy way if I was writing an eclipse plugin. However, as I am writing an standalone application     [ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();]    does not work and I can not write the rest instructions. Let me know if you know a sample code to find references to methods and fields in a standalone java application using JDT.

Comment: If you add `parser.setEnvironment(...)` to your code, you can use `cu.accept(new ASTVisitor(true) { ... })` to visit the AST nodes. In `ASTVisitor` override the `visit` methods at least for  `QualifiedName` and `SimpleName`. With `IBinding binding = node.resolveBinding();` you have a method call or reference if and only if `binding instanceof IMethodBinding` is true and for a field access the following is true: `binding instanceof IVariableBinding` and `((IVariableBinding)binding).isField()`.

Answer (score 2):

The JDT search engine needs an **index**. Within the IDE the index is created during workspace build. This means without a workspace there is no out-of-the-box approach to using the search engine.

It may *in theory* be possible to implement your own index, but that can definitely not be recommended.

Two options remain:

1. As mentioned in a comment use your own traversal of existing classes, or
2. Let your application initialize a workspace behind the scenes into which your code is imported as real Java projects. After a build of that workbench, the search engine should be available. All this could happen in a headless application with no need to fire up the Eclipse UI.

For inspirations regarding option (2) you could start here:

- PDE's [CoreTestApplication](https://git.eclipse.org/c/pde/eclipse.pde.ui.git/tree/ui/org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime/src/org/eclipse/pde/internal/junit/runtime/CoreTestApplication.java), which is the headless application used, e.g., for running JDT's own tests. A workspace is automatically available in the locations passed using the `-data` command line argument.
- JDT's [AbstractJavaModelTests](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core.tests.model/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/tests/model/AbstractJavaModelTests.java), which provides tons of utilities for programmatically creating & configuring Java projects.
- Subclasses of AbstractJavaModelTests which have gazillions of examples how those Java projects are used, including *search*.

If you want to see it all live, I suggest you set up a workspace with JDT and PDE projects in source. The easiest way would be to [use Oomph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Code_Setup_Using_Oomph) for this.

The above CoreTestApplication will be run, if you select any test class, invoke `Run as > Run configurations...` then create a launch configuration of type `JUnit Plug-in Test` and on tab `Main` select `Run an application: [No Application] - Headless Mode`.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code from second option.

Comment: @Arash Maybe you might be interested by the examples I put on GitHub https://jmini.github.io/jdt-experiments/#programcreek-examples. I run JDT code inside JUnit-Test and I have separated the examples in 2 categories: standalone vs requiring osgi